# Rename string values in a column when multiple conditions are not met

Tags: r

I have an age range data column that looks like this:

```
data <- c("<18", "956", "675", "18-30", "31-50", "50+", "543" "Unknown")
```

Now, I want to rename the all whole number characters as "Unknown" with the new column looking like:

```
data <- c("<18", "18-30", "31-50", "50+", "Unknown")
```

I have tried using this:

```
if(data$age_range !="<18" || data$age_range !="18-30" || data$age_range !="31-50" || data$age_range !="50+") 
{data$age_range2 = "Unknown"}
```

But it renames all the values to `"Unknown"`

I also tried using `ifelse`, but it's not working either. I'm quite new to R and would appreciate all the help I can get.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert data to numeric and rename whole numbers as "Unknown".

```
data <- c("<18", "956", "675", "18-30", "31-50", "50+", "543", "Unknown")

data[which(!is.na(as.numeric(data)))] <- "Unknown"

data
```

**Result**

```
[1] "<18"     "Unknown" "Unknown" "18-30"   "31-50"   "50+"     "Unknown" "Unknown"
```

If you want to keep only one "Unknown",

```
sort(unique(data))
# [1] "<18"     "18-30"   "31-50"   "50+"     "Unknown"
```